# CSS selector for elements with certain content (material design icon)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, icons, material-design

I need to add some CSS for all the icons on the page that represent a check mark. It is any chance to do this without add additional class, just with CSS? Basically, it is a CSS selector for elements containing certain content or another way to archive this?

```
<i class="material-icons">check</i>
```

I don't want to add another class because it is a big app and I need to be something general, but only for this type of icons, "check".
Something like i[content=check].

*I saw [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text) but is a question posted 8 years ago.

Comment: Not possible with CSS unfortunately

Comment: @ovokuro This is what I know too, but I really needed a solution in the fast time possible and review all the CSS documentation would take me some time. I hoped it is something I just don't know now...

Comment: @boltclock That question is 8 years old! I saw it, but 8 years in CSS is a long time!

Comment: Nothing has changed in 8 years.

Comment: @BoltClock Ok, thanks.